# WSO2-IS 5.11.0 - Username should be an E-Mail address

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to log on WSO2-IS new console and myaccount as user admin and I'm getting an error:

http://localhost:9443/console/login
http://localhost:9443/myaccount/login

```
Invalid username! Username should be an E-Mail address.
```

I've already check user permission on carbon console as admin and it seems OK:
[image]

Comment: Have you enabled email as username feature? https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/#using-email-address-as-the-username

Comment: Yep. But I hadn't added user admin@wso2.com as super_admin. Now is not showing the error when I try to log with user admin@wso2.com but the page is getting white with an error on console: `Uncaught (in promise) Invalid id_token in the token response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the tenant to enable email as domain but I forgot to put the user admin to use email address as the username:

```
[tenant_mgt]
enable_email_domain= true

[super_admin]
username = "admin@wso2.com"
password = "admin"
```

I also added this user to the roles "Application/Console" and "Application/My Account".